# Windows Phone SQL Server CE - Retrieve underlying database schema for upgrade

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, windows-phone

Windows Phone 7.1 supports SQL Server CE and LINQ to SQL, as well as upgrading the database via DatabaseSchemaUpdater.

On other platforms I would read the database schema tables (e.g. `sys.objects`) to view the current schema and work out what tables/columns need to be upgraded.

Given that no direct SQL access is allowed on Windows Phone, how can retrieve the current database schema?

Comment: But even with the schema knowledge, you would not be able to add any tables/columns, as you cannot execute direct SQL code. See this walkthorugh: Walkthrough: Updating a Local Database Application for Windows Phone http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: You can use the `DatabaseSchemaUpdater` for that. I only needed to get to the schema to find out what I needed to add via the `DatabaseSchemaUpdater`.

Comment: But why not just use version numbers?

Comment: The main reason is so you don't have to manually the database upgrade script for every version increment. If you can find the existing schema and the target schema programmatically then you can upgrade automatically. This means I only have to write one set of code and I can forget about it; the app will take care of itself. I've done this for iOS and Android and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server CE still includes the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` tables, but it is a little tricky to access them as no direct SQL access is allowed.

However, you can create a `DataContext` which maps to these tables:

```
public class SchemaContext : DataContext
{
    public SchemaContext()
        : base("Data Source=isostore:/Database.sdf")
    {
        if (!this.DatabaseExists())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use the SchemaContext on a database which doesn't exist");
        }
    }

    public Table<Table> Tables;
    public Table<Column> Columns;

    [Table(Name = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns")]
    public class Column
    {
        [Column(Name = "TABLE_NAME")]
        public string TableName { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "COLUMN_NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "DATA_TYPE")]
        public string DataType { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "ORDINAL_POSITION")]
        public int OrdinalPosition { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "IS_NULLABLE")]
        public string IsNullableString { get; set; }

        public bool IsNullable
        {
            get { return this.IsNullableString == "YES"; }
            set { this.IsNullableString = value ? "YES" : "NO"; }
        }

    }

    [Table(Name = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables")]
    public class Table
    {
        [Column(Name = "TABLE_NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "TABLE_TYPE")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can then read the schema with the following code:

```
using (var schemaContext = new SchemaContext())
{
    foreach (var table in schemaContext.Tables)
    {

    }
}
```

It's important to create a separate context for these tables, as otherwise the `DataContext.CreateDatabase` call will attempt to create these schema tables, which will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Walkthrough for Updating a Local Database Application for Windows Phone on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which advocates using the `DatabaseSchemaVersion` on the `DatabaseSchemaUpdater` - i.e:

```cs
// Set the new database version.
DatabaseSchemaUpdater dbUpdater = db.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion = APP_VERSION;
dbUpdater.Execute();
```

You can query the version and add the bits that you add in each release, without having to worry about the current schema (after all, it'll be a known configuration as long as you remember to keep the version numbers updated correctly.)